# How did Joseph inherit Hamon from Jonathan?

Tags: jojos-bizarre-adventure

I was watching *JoJo's Bizarre Adventure* and on the episode where Jonathan dies, Erina takes a random child.

When Part 2 started, how did Joseph "inherit Hamon from Jonathan" if he isn't directly related to him?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

He inherited the Hamon ability from

> His mother, Lisa Lisa. She is an expert in Hamon. Well, since they have another Hamon's user other than Joseph in his family, the percentage Jonathan inherited the Hamon's is quite huge. Also his father, Goerge Joestar II was the son of Erina Joestar. However, George Joestar II did not inherit Jonathan's Hamon ability. Instead, his son, Joseph Joestar, had the ability of Hamon.

But from [Wikia](http://jojo.wikia.com/wiki/Joseph_Joestar/History), it stated that he got Hamon's ability from

> Jonathan Joestar.
>
>  The young Joseph developed early an ability to use the Ripple inherited from his grandfather, first displaying it when Speedwagon was being kidnapped.

Here is a video on [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dwT1iZV7FD4) when he used Hamon for the first time

A user from the JoJo's Wikia page explains that too.

> His father is Jonathan and Erina's son, George II. Lisa Lisa is the one who isn't related. Though I expect having some of Lisa's blood helped with learning it faster.

Answer (score 4):

Joseph *is* Jonathan's descendant. Erina was already pregnant when they boarded that ship, the random child she saved later married her son and gave birth to Joseph.

Answer (score 0):

"George Joestar II was born just months after his father died at the hands of Dio Brando. His mother, Erina, was pregnant at the time of Dio’s assault and raised George primarily by herself. He grew up to marry the child who was saved by Erina at the time. Together, they had a son named Joseph Joestar." Taken from JoJo's bizzare adventure wiki search

Answer (score 0):

George Joestar II was hinted to have hamom by speedwagon himself. He said that George was an ordinary man however he had the makings of a Hamon master which means that if he had been taught then he would've been able to control his hamon at will. Most likely George had the same experience of hamon as his son did before he had gone through hamon training. So basically sub consciously using hamon without realizing it. So he basically inherited from both of his parents.

Comment: this doesn't really answer the question, as the question goes under the assumption that Joseph is not blood-related to the Joestar line. OP didn't realize that Erina was pregnant already by the time they took the ship, so he/she believed that she just raised the child she saved and had no true Joestar descendant. Whether George had Hamon is of no consequence to this question.

Answer (score 0):

But he is. He is his grandson. Jonathan and Erina had George, later he and Lisa Lisa would have Joseph. He is 25% Jonathan. You could find family trees out there that also show more of the joestar family because once dio took Jonathans body it got a bit more complicated. For the hamon explanation i think George had a bit of hamon once said but im not sure but Lisa Lisa was trained by straitzo which means even if he isnt a joestar his mother is a hamon user.